# Two same span elements but have different width

Tags: javascript, html

I create two span elements and add them to DOM with visibility = hidden.
After adding both span element to DOM, I get width and height of both elements.

Surprisingly, both width and height are different.

text, font-size, font-family all are same in both span.
What could be the reason for difference in size?

```
var sp1 = goog.dom.createDom('span', null);
sp1.innerText = text; 
sp1.style.fontSize = "60px";
sp1.style.fontFamily = family;
sp1.style.visibility = "hidden";
goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, sp1);

var sp2 = goog.dom.createDom('span', null);
sp2.innerText = text; 
sp2.style.fontSize = "60px";
sp2.style.fontFamily = family;
sp2.style.visibility = "hidden";
goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, sp2);

var sz1 = goog.style.getSize(sp1);
var sz2 = goog.style.getSize(sp2);

assert(sz1 == sz2)
```

HTML of page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ff.css">
        <style>
            #id3{
            /*font-family: abracadabra, Orator W01 Slanted, Alpha Jazz W00 Regular;*/
            font-family: abracadabra, Orator W01 Slanted;
            }
            #id4{
            font-family: Alpha Jazz W00 Regular, Orator W01 Slanted, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Web Fonts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="id1">1. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</div>
        <div id="id2">2. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</div>
        <div id="id3">3. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</div>
        <div id="id4">4. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</div>
        <div id="test1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 2; width: auto; right: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); display: none;">
            <div style="border-bottom-width: 5px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(8, 12, 18); padding: 10px 5px;">
                <div style="float: left; background-image: url(logo.png); padding-left: 25px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 18px; background-position: 0% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">test</div>
                <div style="float: right;"><img src="logo.png" style="margin: 0px;"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="test2"></div>
            <div id="test3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span style="font-size: 60px; font-family: Helvetica; visibility: hidden;">3. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</span>
        <span style="font-size: 60px; font-family: Helvetica; visibility: hidden;">3. Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The span in questions are the two span at end of html document.
Size of 1st = (1217, 67)
Size of second = (1267, 136)

Comment: Is the behavior the same in all browsers?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: The reason is most likely the browser. Spans have no style by default and they aren't block elements, so it renders them however it wants. At least that's my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the HTML.
Consider this: the font-size you have set for those spans is quite big, and when the window is not wide enough the text inside the spans starts to wrap.
Spans have `display:inline;` by default and when wrapped the two text will appear as one BUT with different wrapping, because the second continues immediately after the first and its text is most probably broken on a different place.
If you set `display:block;` for those spans there should be no difference.

Comment: I am a javascript newbie. I only need to measure the width text would take. So, If I use div instead of span, would there be any issue as div is automatically block element?

Comment: In the context of this problem - there should not be any issue.

Answer (score 1):

If they are next to differently sized elements (such as being next to a div rather than on their own separate line) they would be different sizes as they are inline elements and not block level elements.